# Is View recreated when i close an action sheet in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, actionsheet

I Have this following code:

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel
    @State private var showLogoutOptions = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    LogoutButton(showLogoutOptions: $showLogoutOptions)
                    
                }
            }
            .actionSheet(isPresented: $showLogoutOptions) {
                ActionSheet(
                    title: Text("Settings"),
                    message: Text("What you want to do?"),
                    buttons: [
                        .destructive(
                            Text("Sign Out"),
                            action: loginViewModel.handleSignOut
                        ), .cancel()
                    ]
                )
            }
        }    }
}

struct LogoutButton: View {
    
    @Binding var showLogoutOptions: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            showLogoutOptions = true
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "gear")
                .font(.system(size: 24))
                .bold()
                .foregroundStyle(.black)
        }
    }
}
```

And when i dismiss the action sheet, the showLogoutOptions is false again. So, is my view recreated when i dismiss the action sheet or another proccess runs internally?

I tried to read apple's documentation but found nothing about it.

Comment: View structs are created and diffed all the time, but you shouldn't worry about it because structs are lightweight value types created on the memory stack so it's like creating an int which you wouldn't care about. Your `LoginViewModel` is a big problem though because that is a heavy object, you should move that data into the View structs.

Answer (score 0):

> Is View recreated when i close an action sheet in swiftUI?

First I'll assume "close an action sheet" means selecting "Cancel" on the action sheet. I'm not sure what `loginViewModel.handleSignOut` does so can't really reason about it.

Then, we need to figure out what it means for the "View" to be "recreated".

Do you mean `ProfileView.init` is called? We can't be sure. It is not guaranteed that SwiftUI will call your `init`, nor is it guaranteed that it *won't*.

Do you mean `ProfileView.body` is accessed again? Seeing how you also passed `$showLogoutOptions` (which changed after the action sheet is dismissed) to `LogoutButton`, `ProfileView.body` will probably be evaluated again to see if anything in `LogoutButton` needs to be updated (and there isn't, in this situation).

Or do you mean the buttons and navigation bar *on screen* change to a different button and navigation bar? They are probably not changed. SwiftUI compares what `ProfileView.body` retuned last time, with what it returned this time, and finds that practically nothing has changed except the action sheet being dismissed, so it won't make a new button or a new navigation bar.